React rendering delay (useState, useEffect)
Really need advice on useState asynchrony
I have a filter in my project, everything is ready, it works, but with a stack delay of 1 step. I've read that it's because of the asynchronous response and that it's fixed with useEffect, I feel like I'm close to a solution, but I can't get hold of it. I'll describe it in more detail.
Generally speaking, I have

Initializing useState variables

const [KatallogData, setKatallogData] = useState({

    filteredProjects: props.projects, // List of filtered objects (initially equal to the entire list)
    ProjectsList: <></>, // The variable to which I save the rendered list (Initially empty, but since the program starts immediately useEffect - it is filled)
    Filtr_state: {
      sch: [],
      course: [],
      type: [],
      tags: [],
      role: [],}
      } // And a collection of array state lists, it is filtered
);


A function that updates filter status values

const FiltrStateHandler = (event) => {
    setKatallogData((previousState) => {

        return{
          ...previousState, //Setting the previous values
          Filtr_state: event, // Updating the filter state variable
          filteredProjects: *New Value*, //In a certain way, I assign a new list, already filtered
        }

      });
  }


useEffect, which adds a ready-made element to the variable that needs to be rendered

useEffect(() => {
    
    setKatallogData(
      previousState => {
        return{
          ...previousState,
          ProjectsList : <div>
            {KatallogData.filteredProjects.map(data => (

            <Conteiner
                card_data={data.card_data} 
                data={data.data} 
                GoToProject = {GoToProjectHandler} /> //A container element is a ready-made object that is created based on data from a list

                ))}
          </div>,
        }
      }
    )
    console.log(KatallogData.filteredProjects);
  },[KatallogData.Filtr_state])

In general, hoping that useEffect would see the change in the state of the filter and change the rendered list, I did it. But it turned out that nothing works anyway. No. Everything works. But it works with a delay.
I click on the first filter item - nothing happens
I click on the second filter item - the first filter point occurs
I click on the third point of the filter - I already have the first and second ones drawn. Help please! I've already pulled all the hair out of my head, how do I fix it?
I've tried all of the above. I've read articles, watched videos, but nothing comes out, you're my last hope!

console.log(KatallogData.filteredProjects);  what is the point of this? Logging state is useless, especially when you log it before the setter has been applied. I also wouldn't recommend storing JSX elements in state; save the display for your component's return value
